# QT overview/tutorial?

Tags: c++, qt

Does anyone know of any good tutorials/articles which give a broad overview of QT? I'm not looking for a verbose "type this in and this is what it does" kind of tutorial (e.g. [Nokia's/Troll Tech's tutorials](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.3/tutorial.html), I can look at the api docs up for this stuff), but rather something which explains the thought process and considerations which go into making a QT app (for example, the idea of connecting signals to slots, what a widget is and isn't, how the API is organized, etc.).

Comment: This should not have been closed. It was specific, and has a fantastic, helpful answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I recommend reading the following conceptual documents from the Qt Documentation itself:

#### The Core

- [**Object Model**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/object.html) presents the why and how Qt extends the plain C++ object model with the metaobject compiler and what features it adds.
- [**Object Trees and Ownership**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html) illustrates the preferred way of managing dynamically allocated QObjects in Qt. (Notice: *preferred*, not *mandatory*.)
- [**Signals and Slots**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) explains this basic concept in greater depth.
- [**Container Classes**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/containers.html) presents the STL-compatible, collection-like classes adopted by the Qt API. An important concept, [implicit sharing](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/implicit-sharing.html), is also introduced.
- [**The Qt Resource System**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html) describes how data can be embedded in your program or library and accessed at runtime through a special file system.
- [**You're doing it wrong**](https://www.qt.io/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong) is a blog post explaining how to properly use the QThread class. This is a good read because the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-starting.html) and [all examples](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-mandelbrot.html) are wrong.
- [**Debugging Techniques**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/debug.html) are a few debugging tips that are peculiar to Qt. In particular, it explains how to use the `qDebug` construct.

Here's the [full list of core documents](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/topics-core.html).

#### GUI and Graphics

- [**Widgets and Layouts**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-index.html) defines what widgets are and how they are assembled on the screen.
- [**Window and Dialog Widgets**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/application-windows.html) explains the subtle difference between what Qt treats as windows and what it treats as widgets.
- [**Layout Management**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) goes into further detail about widget layout. If you use the built in UI designer, you'll rarely need to fiddle with layout classes directly, but the concepts are nevertheless important.
- [**Paint System**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/paintsystem.html) is how Qt draws stuff.
- [**Coordinate System**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/coordsys.html) illustrates how Qt interprets graphics coordinates on painting devices.
- [**Qt Quick**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-index.html) is the new way of building pretty UIs.

Here's the full list of [GUI and Graphics documents](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/topics-ui.html).

By the time you understand the basics, the rest of the API is very cohesive, consistent and easy to grasp.

Answer (score 6):

You can try [C++ GUI Programming with QT4](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/books/view/c_gui_programming_with_qt_4_2nd_edition_the_official_c_qt_book)

Answer (score 0):

[The Foundations of Qt Development](http://www.apress.com/9781590598313)  is great. Both the book and the source code are useful.